Как подключится к базе данных?
Зарегистрировался в 7m.pl. Создал базу данных, в коде на Python пытаюсь к ней подключится. Пишет ошибку pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'http://sql2.7m.pl' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)").
БД работает на PhpMyAdmin
Вот код:
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(host='http://sql2.7m.pl', user='{user}', passwd='{password}')
cursor = db.cursor()
query = ("SHOW DATABASES")
cursor.execute(query)
for r in cursor:
    print(r)


Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь подключиться к базе данных по HTTP-адресу, а это неправильно. База данных MySQL не доступна по HTTP, она использует свой собственный протокол.

db = pymysql.connect(host='sql2.7m.pl', user='{user}', passwd='{password}', port=3306) 
cursor = db.cursor() 
query = ("SHOW DATABASES") 
cursor.execute(query) 
for r in cursor: 
    print(r)


Если речь идёт про хостинг 7m.pl, то БД у них не доступна для подключения из вне, только localhost.
Если скрипт запускается на хостинге, то используйте host='localhost' или host='127.0.0.1'

А какой тогда бесплатный хостинг посоветуете?

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь подключиться к базе данных по HTTP-адресу, а это неправильно. База данных MySQL не доступна по HTTP, она использует свой собственный протокол.
import pymysql   
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='{user}', passwd='{password}', port=3306)  
cursor = db.cursor()  
query = ("SHOW DATABASES")  
cursor.execute(query)  
for r in cursor:      
    print(r)


Подключение к базе данных есть у меня на наглядном примере(простенькое приложение с использованием БД) https://disk.yandex.ru/d/PPgEWpnHcNwgdg

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
